# Could commit operation cover others' modification without conflict warning?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I seldom execute `update` operation before `commit` because I think once others have modified the file already, then when I `commit` that file the conflict warnings would occur. At least I wouldn't cover others' submission.

But is it possible that I might cover others' submission without warning message when using `commit` operation?

In other words, must I always execute `update` operation before `commit` to avoid covering others' submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always update, for sure. Otherwise, under normal conditions (every project is different), how can you make sure that your changes are working fine with other developer's changes? It's not a matter of only conflicts. Say, a java project. You add a class import to the class that you are working on.... but then on one of the recent revisions from other developers, that class you are importing is gone.... you will commit, *no conflict whatsoever* but the project is **busted**.

Comment: I never used java, can you explain why the project is busted?

Comment: That's just an example of how to break a project by not updating and pushing without conflicts.... in this case, you added a dependency (say) on a file that existed on the project.... on your working copy it was all perfect, you compile, it works.... but while you were working, another developer removed _that_ file that your code depends on.... you didn't notice because you didn't update.... you push, it goes fine (no other developer changes things on the lines of code that you did.... no conflict)... but now your just-pushed code is depending on a file that is _gone_. So it's busted.